# Ubuntu tweak has no reset option

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I don't have a reset option on ubuntu. I have see the small buttons on the end but nothing is their on my one. Is this because this is a old version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it because you have a old version. re-download and install Ubuntu tweak, get the daily ppa from Ubuntu tweak (you can do this by using Ubuntu tweak).

also look at this http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2010/08/08/feature-sneak-peak-reset-setting.html

i hope this helps.

Comment: any of the above will do!